# How to manipulate DOM with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dom

As the title said, I have some DOM manipulation tasks. For example, I want to:
- find all H1 element which have blue color.
- find all text which have size 12px.
- etc..

How can I do it with Rails?

Thank you.. :)

**Update**

I have been doing some research about extracting web page content based on this paper-> http://www.springerlink.com/index/A65708XMUR9KN9EA.pdf

The summary of the step is:

1. get the web url which I want to be extracted (single web page)
2. grab some elements from the web page based on some visual rules (Ex: grab all **H1 which have blue color**)
3. process the elements with my algorithm
4. save the result into my database.

-sorry for my bad english-

Comment: Could you please expand upon what you are trying to achieve (what you are doing) so that I can offer more specific advice for your problem? Thanks.

Comment: Based upon your updated, I'd recommend changing your question to something like: "How to parse a HTML document based on visual criteria with Ruby"

Answer (score 9):

If what you're trying to do is manipulate HTML documents inside a rails application, you should take a look at [Nokogiri](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri).

It uses XPath to search through the document. With the following, you would find any h1 with the "blue" css class inside a document.

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.stackoverflow.com'))
doc.xpath('//h1/a[@class="blue"]').each do |link|
    puts link.content
end
```

After, if what you were trying to do was indeed parse the current page dom, you should take a look at JavaScript and JQuery. Rails can't do that.

Comment: This was my original approach as well, but if you read through that paper synopsis, he's not asking for a css class "blue", but actually something the color blue across multiple sites with potentially wildly different CSS and markup schemes.

Answer (score 2):

http://railscasts.com/episodes/190-screen-scraping-with-nokogiri

Answer (score 1):

To reliably sort out what color an arbitrary element on a webpage is, you would need to reverse engineer a browser (to accurately take into account stylesheets, markup hacks, broken tags, images, etc).

A far easier approach would be to embed an existing browser such as [gecko](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_Embedding_Basics) into a custom application of your making.

As your spider would browse pages, it would pass them to your embedded instance of gecko  where you could use [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getComputedStyle) to pull what color an individual element happens to be.

You originally mentioned wanting to use Ruby on Rails for this project, Rails is a framework for writing presentational applications and really a bad fit for a project like this.

As a starting point, I'd recommend you check out RubyGnome, and in particular RubyGnome's [Gtk::MozEmbed](http://ruby-gnome2.sourceforge.jp/hiki.cgi?Gtk%3A%3AMozEmbed) functionality.

Comment: Thanks, Mike.
Is it works with css property too?
For example: I want to select only H1 which have blue color.

Comment: This isn't what the OP wants. He wants to do all the processing on the server-side, not in JavaScript.

Comment: I posted my answer prior to his update (when it did appear that he wanted a client side solution).