# Is there a way to select html elements with a certain class with ruby?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, get

If I use

```
require 'net/http'

source = Net::HTTP.get('stackoverflow.com', '/index.html')
```

to extract the source code from a url, is there a way, in ruby, to find all link elements with a certain class, and then to extract the `href` attribute of those urls and put them in an array? (I know how I would do this in javascript but not in ruby.)

Perhaps I do not want to use `net/http`?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds to me like [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) would be perfect for you.

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'openuri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://stackoverflow.com/index.html'))
doc.xpath('//h3/a[@class="foo"]').each do |element|
  # do something with element
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [Mechanize](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/) and look into [this](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/Mechanize/Page/Link.html) page.

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'hpricot'

source = open('stackoverflow.com/index.html').read # get raw html

doc = Hpricot(source) # parse with Hpricot
links = doc.search("//a[@class~='foo_bar']").collect { |a| a[:href] } # search for all links with 'foo_bar' class and then collect array of links
```

NB: code is not optimized, so read Hpricot documentation if you'd like to improve it ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can use HTML/XML parsers: nokogiri, mechanize

Answer (score 0):

[Hpricot](http://hpricot.com/) is a nice XML/HTML parser you could use to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try searching Parsing HTML / DOM to look for relevant results. I'm sure there are a ton out there.

[How to manipulate DOM with Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611237/how-to-manipulate-dom-with-ruby-on-rails)